# Guessing at string encodings for stream of bytes in log file

Tags: ruby, encoding

**tl;dr summary**: Given a stream of bytes representing a string in an unknown encoding, what encodings and in what order should I attempt to interpret the bytes to get the best chance of finding the 'right' encoding?

#### Example of the Problem

I have a file `arrows.txt` that I happen to know has been saved using UTF-8 with the single-character content of `⇈`. If I pretend that I *do not know* what the encoding of this file is, the following Ruby code on Windows fails:

```
s = IO.read('foo.txt')
p s.encoding,        #=> #<Encoding:IBM437>
  s.valid_encoding?, #=> true
  s.chars.to_a       #=> ["\xE2", "\x87", "\x88"]
```

It 'fails' because it tells me that the file actually had the contents `Γçê`, and that everything is fine (the encoding is valid).

#### Real World Scenario

I have [Nginx](http://nginx.net) log files and Akamai log files that don't have any particular encoding for the queries they record, which I need to process and store data for in a database as UTF-8. Most of the time interpreting each line as UTF-8 produces a string with a valid encoding, but sometimes it does not.

I want to ask Ruby to try a variety of encodings for each line, to find one that is valid and *likely* (but of course not guaranteed) to be correct.

#### Failed Attempt

I originally wrote the following code:

```
def guess_encoding( str, result='utf-8', *encodings )
  # Try every encoding if none were passed in
  encodings = Encoding.list if encodings.empty?

  # Keep forcing a new encoding until we find one that is valid
  unless encodings.find{ |e| str.force_encoding(e) && str.valid_encoding? }
    raise "None of the supplied encodings was valid"
  end

  # Convert from the valid encoding to the desired, replacing 'bad' characters
  str.encode(result, invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
end
```

The problem with this is that the very first encoding in `Encoding.list` is `ASCII-8BIT`, which is valid for all streams of bytes. Thus, if I use my code above and call `s2 = guess_encoding(s)` the result is the string `���` for my three-byte double-arrow character above.

#### Finally, the Question(s)

What order should I test encodings in to provide the greatest chance of having the first `valid_encoding?` be the correct one? Which common encodings are the pickiest about the bytes used, such that I should try them first, and which common encodings are completely permissive, such that I should try them last?

Are there any other heuristics I should use in guessing for correctness? (Is it more likely to be correct if a particular encoding results in fewer characters than another?)

Comment: You can try the [rchardet19](https://rubygems.org/gems/rchardet19) gem. It "takes a sequence of bytes in an unknown character encoding, and attempts to determine the encoding."

Comment: @louism You should make this an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure whether a gem recommendation counted as an answer, but since other are doing it, I figured I'd do it too :-).

Comment: One thing to remember, is `bytes` returns the bytes that constitute the character, but `chars` returns the multibyte characters themselves. So, while `s.bytes.to_a` returns the three bytes, `s.chars.to_a` will return only the single character.

Comment: @theTinMan A good clarification; outputting the `bytes` was really noise. I've updated the question to show that under that particular encoding the `chars.to_a.length` is also three bad characters (the crux of the problem).

Comment: You ask hard questions. Stop that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [rchardet19](https://rubygems.org/gems/rchardet19) gem. It "takes a sequence of bytes in an unknown character encoding, and attempts to determine the encoding." It also gives you a confidence score for the encoding it returns. It has worked for me several times in the past, and looks like it does what you are trying to accomplish.

Example usage:

```
require 'rchardet19'
cd = CharDet.detect("some data")
# => #<struct #<Class:0x102216198> encoding="ascii", confidence=1.0>
```

Comment: Although not a direct answer to the questions I was asking, this is exactly what I needed: a reputable source of encoding guessing that is presumably better than any heuristics I would come up with.

Comment: @Phrogz, don't presume. :-) I was using the Linux equivalent for a while and found lots of cases it failed.

Answer (score 1):

If your code can run on a unix/linux machine, then the [filemagic](https://github.com/ricardochimal/ruby-filemagic) gem may work well for you.

```
gem install ruby-filemagic
```

It is most useful as a tool to determine the encoding of the entire file which can then be used for all lines in the file. The following should help you get started with it:

```
$ irb 
irb(main):001:0> require 'filemagic' 
=> true
irb(main):002:0> fm = FileMagic.new
=> #<FileMagic:0x7fd4afb0>
irb(main):003:0> fm.file('afile.zip') 
=> "Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract"
irb(main):004:0>
```

Comment: Filemagic is fine for the first chunk of a file, but I've run into problems with logs and big HTML files, which could have all sorts of nastiness buried inside. Sometimes we have to read it line by line and handle each separately.

Comment: Not only must this run on Windows, but the comment by @theTinMan is exactly correct: it would appear that these log files have mixed encodings on a per-line basis.

Comment: @Phrogz, as an exercise, add that madness to parsing RSS and Atom feeds. That they were supposed to be XML didn't matter at all; I blew up Hpricot many times and finally got a combination that was unreadable by it entirely, which is why I favor Nokogiri now. I definitely feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

When I was dealing with writing spiders, I always started with ISO-8859-1, followed by Win-1252. The difference between the two are minor, so either should be suitable the majority of the time. My reason for those two first, is I think you are most likely to encounter them.

If something didn't fit those, then I'd just use iconv to convert it to UTF-8, or strip the diacritical accents so it was visually similar to what we'd expect to see, and proceed.

There were times that nothing would be a hit; I had code that extracted all of iconv's encodings and then stripped all the ASCII values and tried to find the encoding with the highest number of hits for the remaining characters. XML and HTML was occasionally so malformed that nothing helped, which was when I'd revert to stripping the accents.